# App running on iPhone 4 has a 320x480 resolution instead of 640x960

Tags: iphone, uiwindow, screen-resolution

I'm creating an iPhone app, which will run on iPhone 3 and iPhone 4.

To that point, I was trying to make the images adjust to the resolution, but it turns out that even when running on the iPhone 4, the size of my window is 320x480.

On the XIB I specified "fullscreen at launch" and for the ViewController I even specified "Wants fullscreen", but I can never get it to recognise the actual resolution.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it running full screen on your iPhone 4? (I don't mean what resolution is being reported, I mean are there black bars around the app - I bet there aren't).

iOS is 'magical' in that you just deal with iPhone 3 size things i.e. xibs etc and it scales it correctly for you on the iPhone 4. You will always see the smaller resolution when you query the display.

To get images to load the correct resolution just create two versions i.e.

myImage.png
  myImage@2x.png

Make the second one exactly twice the size of the first and the iPhone will do the rest.

---

PS There's a property that's been added to UIImageView called scale - it's how the iPhone knows how large to render an image - have a [look at the docs here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006890-CH3-SW39).

Comment: I see. So my source images are already 2x, even though they're not named that way. I'm actually applying a scale down factor when inserting the images. The problem is that I'd like to save the current View to the Saved Photos, but when I do that, it saves an image of 320x480, instead of the full quality one.

Comment: That's odd - I'd expect it to save at the correct resolution. I've no experience saving photos but I'd post another question (including the code you're using) on stack overflow - there's probably someone else out there who can help!

Comment: @Andre - Are you using UIGraphicsBeginImageContext() in taking the snapshot?  On a Retina display, you'll want to use UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions() and set the scale factor to 0.0 to pick up the display's scale factor.  That should create a bitmap that matches the screen resolution of your application window.

Comment: @Brad yes! Let me try that now :)